# Salesforce API - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: api, mavensmate

I'm attempting to update my Salesforce project using MavensMate and Sublime Text. However, it seems that any attempt to connect to Salesforce results in the following error:

```
[OPERATION FAILED]: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

We've tried different orgs, different machines, different wifi networks, even switched over to Eclipse and we're still not able to connect.

Anyone have any idea what's happening here? Seems to be an outage on Salesforce's end of some kind.

Comment: You said you tried with different wifi networks. Are those using the same cable network, though? I've had a similar problem last thursday, but it was my provider's fault, not Salesforce's.

Comment: We tried on two completely different networks - different providers.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the way but it didn't work. Finally I uninstalled the mavensmate and installed it again. It worked. Try this. It might work for you as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Have you checked your instance status at https://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Our instance seems to be up and running, according to the site.

Comment: @crmprogdev no, I was not able to comment topic starter post, and that was only way to provide him some help

Comment: @mike-rocha, I had same problem and toady I tried to use VPN connection and successfully update my project

Comment: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/493#issuecomment-134538119

Comment: @John thanks for this, the solution was mentioned in that thread: "Try to use custom url instead of saying developer or production." Works great now.

Comment: @John Welcome to SF.SE. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, plus click on the links provided in my initial comments to learn more about reputation and commenting. We want your experience here to be a positive one where you'll be able to receive the answers you need and contribute to the community if you choose to. Thank you. Right now, your post is in a queue where it's being voted on for deletion.